# JFileChooser showSaveDialog not working sometimes

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, save, jfilechooser

I'm using Netbeans 7.2 on OS X 10.9. The `JFileChooser.showSaveDialog()` fails on certain occasions. Before I call the `showSaveDialog`, I call `showOpenDialog` to open an .srt file. The show dialog fails only when I open certain files esp. from `/Volumes/..` on a mounted device. Here's the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

public class FileSaver extends JFileChooser {
private int result;
private File subFile;
private File save;
private File filename;
private String rectifiedSub;
private FileNameExtensionFilter filter;

    public FileSaver(File subFile, String rectifiedSub) {  
        this.subFile = subFile;
        this.rectifiedSub = rectifiedSub;
        filename = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
        filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Subtitle Files (*.srt)", "srt");        
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        System.out.println("6");
        this.setDialogTitle("Select destination");        
        System.out.println("6");
        this.setCurrentDirectory(filename);
        System.out.println("6");
        this.setSelectedFile(new File(subFile.getName()));        
        System.out.println("6");
        this.setFileFilter(filter);
        System.out.println("6");
        result = this.showSaveDialog(this);
        System.out.println("6");
        if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {            
            save = fixExtension(this.getSelectedFile());
            write(save);
        }
        this.setVisible(true);        
    }

    public void write(File save) {
        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(save);
            fw.write(rectifiedSub);            
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileSaver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                fw.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FileSaver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }       
    }

    public File fixExtension(File file) {
        if(!FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getName()).equalsIgnoreCase(".srt"))
            file = new File(file.getParentFile(), FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getName()).concat(".srt"));
        return file;
    }

}
```

#### Output:

> 6
>   6
>   6
>   6
>   6

It stops at the 6 before the line `result = this.shhowSaveDialog(this);`. The program freezes after that and the save dialog doesn't show up. It works perfectly fine on some files. Somebody tell me whats happening ?

#### Git: https://github.com/Jimmy-666/Subzero.git

Comment: Can you deliver more information than just "it fails"? How does it fail? Do you get an exception? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: There's no exception. It just freezes at that statement.

Comment: Mmhh ok...  Btw you've noticed that you call 'setVisible' after the call for 'showSaveDialog'? Try to switch both calls.

Comment: Already tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: So the "shwOpenDialog" has no problem during navigation to the remove volume? .. mmm that is strange. Since I'm home now, I can try it myself ...

Comment: I'll upload the whole code

Comment: No necessary, I've tested it on my Mac with Windows as the remote host and I also notice that problem, it just "hangs" on the `showSaveDialog` call. Maybe I can find the source of that problem.

Comment: Do you know which Java Version you're using? You can find it under *File* > *Project Structure...*.

Comment: java version "1.7.0_04"

Comment: As I said, I was able to reproduce your problem (I'm running Yosemite with Java 8) and I got a much more stable program after switching back to Java 6. I'm working with IntelliJ, so I was forced to install Java 6 to run that IDE, but I'm using Java 8 to compile and run other Java applications ([due to bugs with Mac OS X and Java 7/8](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks)), so try to use Java 6 as well (Apple provides a download with JDK 6) and use that try that instead of Java 8.

Comment: The install path of the JDK from Apple is `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`.

Comment: JDK 6 has the same result

Comment: Have you changed the "project sdk" in the "Project Structure" menu? And the compiler level is also on *6*? Btw, you should also run your app with Java 6.

Comment: Check [this](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7161437)

Comment: @Madhan *"ON APPLE JAVA 1.6 IT DOES WORK."* (from you link) As I said, Java 6(°) is much more stable for Mac OS :D. (°) Maybe there is also a difference between Oracle JDK 6 and the one provided by Apple.

Comment: @Tom Yes Just wanted the op to see the official java bug

Comment: @Tom how do I change the compiler level ?

Comment: @Madhan I haven't used java.awt

Comment: @Jimmy You can change both (used JDK and Compiler level) in "Project Structure" menu.